# How can I mark a SOAP Header as optional in WSDL?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, tibco

I have a *wsdl* with an optional header:

```
<s:element name="AuthIdentifier" type="tns:AuthIdentifier"/>
<s:complexType name="AuthIdentifier">
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="identifier" type="s:string"/>
  </s:sequence>
  <s:anyAttribute/>
</s:complexType>
```

The client is using an *integration software* `(tibco)` to connect to my service and claims that the header is required, so he must send it with an empty value:

```
<Header.AuthIdentifier>
   <ns0:AuthIdentifier xmlns:ns0 = "http://www.tal.com/schemas"/>
</Header.AuthIdentifier>
```

How do I make it optional? So that he won't have to send the whole header at all? Is there a `minOccurs` or something like that? Or is it already optional as it is now?

Comment: I have the same problem with Tibco. Did you fix it?

Comment: Is that snippet defining the structure of Header? If it is, try `<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AuthIdentifier" type="tns:AuthIdentifier"/>`

Answer (score 4):

According to "Web Service Contract Design & Versioning" Thomas Erl et al (ISBN-13: 978-0-13-613517-3) Chapter 15.4, Defining SOAP Blocks in WSDL:

> The WSDL 1.1 Specification is unclear about whether SOAP headers
>   described in a WSDL document must be included by consumers or not. The
>   WS-I Basic Profile made it mandatory for consumers to include them,
>   but WDL 2.0 provides the choice as to whether consumers should be
>   forced to include them or not. Page 472.

In WSDL 2.0 you can set the attribute wsdl:required="false" in the custom SOAP header block to indicate whether consumers must include this header block.